# Is there any way to filter and sort emails into folders on the commandline for use with neomutt + mbsync?

Tags: linux, command-line, email, email-filter, neomutt

I've recently transitioned to using neomutt and mbsync for my personal email (setup via [mutt-wizard](https://github.com/lukesmithxyz/mutt-wizard)). I'd like to do the same for my work email, but I get a significant volume of email on that address. I've traditionally relied on Thunderbird filters to sort the email into folders for me upon receipt, to help me manage it.

I'm looking for the best method to achieve a similar effect with commandline tools that would work with neomutt. I'd prefer to do the sorting locally, as this wouldn't require an imap connection (our company email is handled via Gmail so that might be finicky for some clients) but honestly I'd be fine with anything. The desired effect is such that when I open the account in neomutt, the mail has been sorted into folders already.

Desired filters would be matching on all or part of "to" and "from" addresses, and all or part of the subject line.

Is there an existing tool / script that can be added to the toolchain? Or is there a more suitable "neomutt-like" way of managing email in this fashion? I am open to suggestions.

I've searched reddit and the web but come up with nothing; although DDG search results have been wonky lately so maybe I've missed something. I use Debian, but am comfortable compiling software from source if it's not in the repos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using [IMAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol) then [IMAPFilter](https://github.com/lefcha/imapfilter) can filter messages (delete, copy, move, flag, etc.) residing in mailboxes in (one or multiple) remote mail servers. Examples at https://github.com/lefcha/imapfilter/blob/master/samples/config.lua.

Comment: This is very useful! Thank you very much for the answer.